Most efficient way to create a time varying dataframe
I have the following dataframe:
from_year  to_year  id  gender
1990       1993     1   Female
1987       1992     2   Male
2000       2000     3   Male
2010       2011     4   Female

I would like to produce the following time varying dataframe:
id   year   gender
1    1990   Female
1    1991   Female
1    1992   Female
1    1993   Female
2    1987   Male
2    1988   Male
2    1989   Male
2    1990   Male
2    1991   Male
2    1992   Male
3    2000   Male
4    2010   Female
4    2011   Female

What's the most efficient way to convert the top dataframe to the bottom one using python pandas?

Efficient in terms of speed, memory, or both? What are your actual performance requirements? How big is your actual df? For guidance, see What makes a "good" performance question on SO? But maybe you're asking the wrong question: if you don't have any way to do it yet, just ask how to do it. Maybe even a naive approach will be faster than you expect :) I wrote a naive solution myself, but I'm holding off on posting it until the requirements are clarified.

generally, for this i would use a non-equi join; I'll wait to to see if OP updates based on @wjandrea's comments

One way to do this is to create a range from the from_year and to_year values, and then explode that:
df['year'] = [range(x, y+1) for x, y in zip(df.pop('from_year'), df.pop('to_year'))]
df = df.explode('year').reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
    id  gender  year
0    1  Female  1990
1    1  Female  1991
2    1  Female  1992
3    1  Female  1993
4    2    Male  1987
5    2    Male  1988
6    2    Male  1989
7    2    Male  1990
8    2    Male  1991
9    2    Male  1992
10   3    Male  2000
11   4  Female  2010
12   4  Female  2011


Here's one approach:
res = (
    df.reindex(np.repeat(df.index, df['to_year'].sub(df['from_year']).add(1)))
    .pipe(lambda x: 
          x.assign(year=x['from_year'].add(x.groupby('id').cumcount()))
    )
    .loc[:, ['id', 'year', 'gender']]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

Output
    id  year  gender
0    1  1990  Female
1    1  1991  Female
2    1  1992  Female
3    1  1993  Female
4    2  1987    Male
5    2  1988    Male
6    2  1989    Male
7    2  1990    Male
8    2  1991    Male
9    2  1992    Male
10   3  2000    Male
11   4  2010  Female
12   4  2011  Female

Explanation

Get the difference between 'to_year' and 'from_year', adding 1 (Series.sub, Series.add).
Use to repeat the index values with np.repeat and apply df.reindex.
Now, pipe the result (df.pipe), and assign a new column 'year' (df.assign), populated with 'from_year' plus the cumcount per group from 'id' (df.groupby, groupby.cumcount).
Finally, use df.loc to select the desired columns, and add df.reset_index.

Intermediates
# diff years + 1
df['to_year'].sub(df['from_year']).add(1)
0    4 # 1993 - 1990 + 1
1    6
2    1
3    2
dtype: int64

# index values repeated based on diff
np.repeat(df.index, df['to_year'].sub(df['from_year']).add(1))

Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], dtype='int64')

# cumcount values per group to be added to repeated 'from_year' values per group
x.groupby('id').cumcount()

0    0 # 1990 + 0
0    1 # 1990 + 1
0    2 
0    3 
1    0 # 1987 + 0
1    1 # 1987 + 1
1    2 # etc.
1    3
1    4
1    5
2    0
3    0
3    1
dtype: int64

